# Table displays in one line

Tags: html, css, html-table

The problem is in my CSS file:

```
* {
    font-size: 8px;
    float: left;
  }
```

The universal property makes a simple HTML table (loaded later) render in one line.  What's a good way to prevent this from happening without bothering my (imo) elegant CSS too much?

---

edit:
I have tried changing the style property of the returned table to look like

```
style="float: none;"
```

but the table elements still default to floating left...  I'm not exactly clear on the precedence of the css file vs style attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um. A way would be to.. **not float everything**. That is **not** elegant.

If you want a quick solution, probably `table { float:none; } table * { float:none; }`

Comment: and I can always specify floats and nones manually, I was trying to turn this into a learning exercise for style property precedence

Comment: You *shouldn't* float everything. I see no reason at all for it. You should keep elements not floated..

Comment: I had a float: left in all the elements I was working with so I simplified it into the * element, I didn't design it working from all-floats, that would be absurd

Answer (score 0):

You can assign `float: none` to individual elements. That should (hopefully) override the float, though your mileage may vary. You'd probably be advised to do that to every element in the table, including `thead` and `tbody`.

But, as the previous answer said, it might not be a good idea to float everything. I understand you feel it's elegant, but I think it's going to cause more problems for you than this one you're facing now. On a website of even moderate complexity, you'll have a whole lot of elements to style (including inline typographic elements, such as `em`), and I can't imagine you'd want to deal with floating all of them.